# Azure AD Custom Domain doesn't validate

Tags: azure, entra-id

Althoug we added (and can publicly query) a TXT Record in the form MS=ms1223333 Domain validation fails.
When I make a Query I get two TXT records:
[image: External lookup]

Any tips what's wrong or what we are missing?

Comment: Have you looked at the Common issues here? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain#common-verification-issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally found that someone of a different developer team already added the domain.
A better error message would have helped a lot.

Comment: Most times I find Powershell gives better return values.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/dn919677(v=azure.100)#BKMK_ManageDomains

Comment: Unfortunately we sit behind a corporate firewall and can access the internet only via browser. Neither can I download the PS modules (which are a kind of nuget packages but from oneget.. or so) nor am I able to access the internet via powershell.

Comment: I would highly recommend that you and your team get at least one machine (call it a tools server) that has PowerShell and/or the CLI installed on it.  While we are constantly adding functionality to the portal, you can't do everything via the browser.  The commandline is a must for a successful cloud shop.